# Is it possible to activate Fast Fail for TOX jobs?

Tags: python, tox

**Is it possible for us to have a fast-fail option for tox jobs ?** For instance, if a test fails, non of the other ends should not be run. This would be very useful for us in CI workflows.

I checked their documentation and couldn't find any options to do this.

I am aware that this is possible for GitHub-Actions. However, I am not using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently have an open issue to support a fail fast workflow, see https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/578

In other words, this is currently not implemented in `tox`, but in the thread there are various workarounds listed.

Disclaimer: I am one of the `tox` maintainers.